# Slow Processing Sketch

Tags: eclipse, export, processing

My game runs through a processing sketch. When I export the .jar file from Eclipse, the sketch moves incredibly slow, but it runs at the proper speed in the IDE. Is there a way that I can fix the jar file and make it run faster?

Here's a GitHub: [Machlandia GitHub](https://github.com/WeaponGod243/Machlandia/releases/tag/v0.2-indev)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the link and add the relevant code in your question. Links are discouraged because they can break, rendering your question not useful for future readers. It would also help if you had some gif or some video of what happens. By "sketch" do you mean a sprite?

Comment: @TomTsagk A Processing 'sketch' is essentially an applet. [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)) is a Java based language / IDE primary designed for media / arts use & has some terms that can be ambiguous.

Comment: Have you tried running or exporting your sketch from the Processing Sketchbook?

Comment: @Pikalek Ah I see, thanks for the explanation, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @TomTsagk Yeah, there's some terminology to it that's quirky. I even the language name to be problematic - while also awkward in its own way, I thought 'Pro55ing' (as taken from the original home URL) was a better name because it was distinct from 'processing' as verb. I'm not their primary target audience though.

Comment: @Pikalek, what is the Processing Sketchbook?

Comment: The default Processing IDE as shown on their [getting started page](https://processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/). It's possible that Eclipse is doing something unexpected when you're exporting, so I'm wondering how the code behaves in the standard Processing IDE.

Comment: @Pikalek, I will try it in there and edit to tell results.

Comment: @Pikalek, when I tried adding my images into the PDE, it didn't work.

Comment: @TomTsagk, I have zero idea why it's being slow, which is why I linked the GitHub versus posting my entire file of code. I can post the entire thing if you'd like though.

Comment: I downloaded the .zip from your repo & it doesn't compile. Line 6 in `Sign.java` gives '`signFont` cannot be resolved to a variable'.